# How do I fix the positioning of material icons?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to fix the offset between the text and the material icon.

[image]

I have no position editing CSS.

This is the HTML for the two elements.

```
<i class="material-icons md-18 inline">mail</i>
<h6 class="inline">info@ex.com</h6>
```

The CSS from here https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons

---

I attempted to use things like `margin` and that just offsets the entire div.

[image: Exaggerated example]

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: @Nikkkshit I have shared all the relevant code

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* fallback */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v134/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><i class="material-icons md-18 inline">mail</i>
  <h6 class="inline">info@ex.com</h6>
</div>
```

- wrap `text` and `icon` in one wrapper div.  Set this wrapper div classname ```.wrapper````.(you can use any name for classname)
- set `.wrapper` to `display:flex;align-items:center`.

```
<html>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <i class="material-icons md-18 inline">mail</i>
   <h6 class="inline">info@ex.com</h6>
  </div>
</html>
<style>
 .wrapper{
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
  }
</style>
```

**I could share working example but I need your code**

Answer (score 0):

The HTML and CSS codes you have are as follows:

```css
/* fallback */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v134/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<i class="material-icons md-18 inline">mail</i>
<h6 class="inline">info@ex.com</h6>
```

The above snippet outputs this:
[image]

To have the text on the same line as the icon, set the text's display to `inline` and add a left margin to it

```css
h6.inline {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

After modifying, the resultant code:

```css
/* fallback */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v134/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

h6.inline {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<i class="material-icons md-18 inline">mail</i>
<h6 class="inline">info@ex.com</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by putting the icons and the `<h6>` into a `<div>` tag. After that you have to make the display of that div flex.
Here is the code:-

```css
.align-div{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:row;
}
```

```html
<div class = "align-div">
<i class="material-icons md-18 inline">mail</i>
<h6 class="inline">info@ex.com</h6>
</div>
```

Same goes with the phone section place them in a div and same process goes on.